# Android webview load data error eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to use a web view to make an HTML to bitmap. Everything was running ok until I try to had my app in the background. I make the app came to the foreground like this

```
Intent it = new Intent("intent.my.action");
it.setComponent(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
MainActivity.class.getName()));
it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext().startActivity(it);
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

After that, I load data to my web view and wait for the onPageCommitVisible to run but never run!!!

webView.loadData(html, "text/html","UTF-8");

Answer (score 0):

I have just add the load data part and the new webclient to a fuction called in the onResume and it is working